# Find html class inside Android WebView

Tags: android, eclipse, class, android-webview

I am trying to create a very simple app on my phone.
My job is to load a webpage, and copy a specific class inside that page (in this case it is address)
A very simple example;

On a random page, i found this line in their source;

```
<div class='address'>A Adress that i should copy on start</div><div class='phone'> 0000000000 (dont need this anyway)</div>
```

As you can see there are two classes, `address` and `phone`
i would like to copy the contents inside the address class so that would be `A Adress that i should copy on start`

Does somebody know if this is possible ?
I have looked up, but there was not much info avaiable, especially for android...

Thank you for your time.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps

**Step 1:** Inject your javascript function over the webpage

**Step 2:** Call your java method from javascript using a `JavaScriptInterface`

Below code goes in your `Activity`'s `onCreate` method

```
final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.browser);  
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  

JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
        {  
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                    "var content = document.getElementsByClassName('address')[0].innerHTML; " +
"window.JSInterface.printAddress(content);" +
                    "})()");  
        }  
    });  

webview.loadUrl("http://YOUR-WEB-URL.com/");
```

Where your `JavaScriptInterface` can be this

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    private Activity activity;

    public JavaScriptInterface(Activity activiy) {
        this.activity = activiy;
    }

    public void printAddress(String address){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Address: "+address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for sharing your idea.
i will try this asap and will let you know if it worked !